# How to open a pull request against an upstream repo using BitBucket Api?

Tags: bitbucket, fork, pull-request, bitbucket-api

Let's say I have a workspace and repo called acme/widget, and I have a fork of that called brianc/widget. Using the BitBucket api, how can I create a pull request from my repo to the upstream?

In the [docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-post) there doesn't seem to be a way to do this kind of cross-repo pull request creation, since it seems that `branch` is the only variable allowed. Any ideas?